# Evitar duplicar datos al momento de ingresar un nuevo usuario

Tags: vb6

Tengo una conexión de base de datos a `access` y visual de `excel`
¿Cómo puedo hacer el código para la consulta que me permita mandar un `msgbox` que me diga si el usuario ya esta registrado?
se que se ocupa `recordset`

El código que tengo:

```
reuc.Open  "SELECT usuario" & "FROM Usuarios" & "WHERE usuario='" & TXT_USER.Text & "' "
```

Quiero saber que valor arroja éste, si así se puede poner en un `if`:

```
if reuc = TXT_USER.TEXT THEN  
    msgbox "Usuario existente"    
end if
```

Comment: ¿Hay alguna posibilidad de que migres tu aplicación a VB.Net?

Answer (score 2):

Así debería ser tu if

```
if reuc("usuario") = TXT_USER.TEXT THEN  
    msgbox "Usuario existente"    
end if
```

Te recomiendo controlar antes que tu `recordset` no esté vacío.

```
If not reuc.EOF THEN

end If
```

Si tu consulta obtiene mas de un usuario (puede sonar raro, pero es para que lo tengas en cuenta), deberías recorrer el `recordset` entero y una vez encontrado el usuario salir del `do until`:

```
Dim encontrado As Boolean
Do until reuc .EOF and not encontrado
    if reuc("usuario") = TXT_USER.TEXT THEN  
        msgbox "Usuario existente"  
        encontrado = true
    end if

    reuc.MoveNext
Loop
```